# Passing trainable parameters for weighted loss in Keras, while using generator for inputs

Tags: python, parameters, keras, deep-learning, loss

While making a **custom loss function** in Keras, I encountered a problem when applying trainable weights for a different type of losses. Below code snippet shows my approach to learn **the weights - c_a, c_b, c_c** for three losses at the same time. I used a generator to get the input and that's the main difference from several other questions answered by @Daniel Möller.

I defined a `custom_loss` function inside a main method `train_test`, which includes a model generation part. To train those parameters, I defined an input layer `weight_input = keras.Input((3,))` and add it as an additional input for `keras.Model`, also put `weight_input` as a parameter for `custom_loss` function.

**Here is my question:**

I would like to define three values `weight_inputs: c_a, c_b, c_c` as [1,1,1] and want them to be changed while training goes on. So I guess those values do not have to be included for each data samples (like other inputs: `visit_input, areas_input, visit_features_input` in a generator function) But I am still not clear how to pass those three values to   Should I add additional input on my existing generators?

Currently the results of `data.train_data_generator` and `data.test_data_generator` includes `visit_input, areas_input, visit_features_input`. Then how should I pass those weights to `customer_loss` function and make them trainable?

```
from data import *
import keras

def train_test(self):

    def custom_loss(weight_inputs):
        def _custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            # Calculation part of loss_a, loss_b, loss_c are removed too.
            # Scalar value - c_a, c_b, c_c - should be an element of weight_inputs, respectively. 
            total_loss = self.c_a * loss_a + self.c_b * loss_b + self.c_c * loss_c 

            return total_loss

        return _custom_loss


    # ... Additional NN structure before logits 
    # (visit_input, areas_input, visit_features_input, weight_input were put in a proper way)

    # Final prediction layer    
    logits = keras.layers.Dense(365, activation=keras.activations.softmax)(concat)

    # weight parameter input for custom loss function
    weight_input = keras.Input((3,))

    # Define a model and compile
    self.model = keras.Model(inputs=[visit_input, areas_input, visit_features_input, weight_input], outputs=logits)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                       loss=custom_survival_loss(weight_input),
                       )

    # Train
    self.train_data = data.train_data_generator()
    self.test_data = data.test_data_generator()

    # Fit
    self.history = self.model.fit_generator(
        generator=self.train_data,
        steps_per_epoch=train_data_size//FLAGS.batch_size,
        epochs=FLAGS.train_epochs,
        callbacks=[TrackTestDataPerformanceCallback(data, self.test_data)]
    )

    self.result = self.model.predict_generator(
        generator=self.test_data,
        steps=1
    )

    # Evaluate function (The trained weights should be used in this method too)
    evaluate(data, self.result)
```

Generators are defined as below. (Before adding `weight_inputs` part)

```
    def train_data_generator(self):
        def __gen__():
            while True:
                idxs = list(self.df_train.index)
                np.random.shuffle(idxs)
                for idx in idxs:
                    visit = self.train_visits.iloc[idx]
                    label = self.df_train.iloc[idx]
                    yield visit['visit_indices'], visit['area_indices'], \
                          [visit[ft] for ft in self.handcrafted_features], \
                          [label[ft] for ft in ['label', 'suppress_time']]

        gen = __gen__()

        while True:
            batch = [np.stack(x) for x in zip(*(next(gen) for _ in range(FLAGS.batch_size)))]
            yield [batch[0].reshape(-1, 1), batch[1], batch[2]], batch[-1]
```

Plus: I would like to maintain several sub loss functions in `custom_loss` since some computations can be reused among different losses.